# Better way to paint a JComponent in java swing

Tags: java, swing, background, paintcomponent

We can paint the background of a Jcomponent in swing and can also place background image. I want to know which is the better way to minimize the memory usage? Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not really sure there is much difference between the two, but it will depend on how you perform the custom painting.  Basically, the end result and means is generally the same...

Comment: *"I want to know which is the better way to minimize the memory usage?"*  This has the distinct smell of premature optimization.  If your app. throws an `OutOfMemoryError`, it has (far) bigger problems than the way paint is used.

Comment: the question doesn't make much sense to me (and wondering about all the upvotes, -1 for balance) - how can _paint background_ be related to memory usage? Even with a huge background _image_ chances are you are doing something wrong (as @AndrewThompson already suspected) in your concrete context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are repainting the area again and again ,then its always better to only repaint the required portion instead of painting entire region.

[Filthy Rich Clients](http://www.filthyrichclients.org) by RomainGuy and Chet Hasse is an excellent  learning source for swing painting techniques

Comment: Thanks @Insane Coder.Is the book referenced is free?

Comment: :Thanks for your time :)

Comment: nitpicking: the question was about memory, not performance